# recorrer un array php con while

Tags: php, array, while, foreach

Tengo el siguiente método:

```
public function reunionDetallada($idReunion_fk)
{
    require_once 'empleado_reunion_DAO.php';

    $dao = new Empleado_reunion_DAO();

    $nexo = new Empleado_reunion();

    $listaReuniones = $dao->obtener_reunion_detallada($idReunion_fk);

    foreach ($listaReuniones as $nexo) {
        echo $nexo->getAsuntoModelo();
        echo $nexo->getFechaModelo();
        echo $nexo->getInicioModelo();
        echo $nexo->getFinModelo();
        echo $nexo->getCosteEstimadoModelo()."<br>";
        break;
    }

    foreach($listaReuniones as $nexo){
        echo $nexo->getNombreModelo();
        echo $nexo->getApellidosModelo();
        echo $nexo->getDepartamento();
        echo $nexo->getFoto()."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    }

    return $listaReuniones;
}
```

El primer bucle me devuelve tantas filas como me devuelva el segundo. Por eso he tenido que poner un break. Porque quiero que el primer bucle solo imprima el primer registro que encuentre, mientras que en el segundo, quiero que imprima todo.

¿Alguien sabe como se haría con un while o de cualquier otra forma para poder evitar el break (ya que este suele verse como mala práctica...)?

Comment: Quita el `foreach` y accedes a la primera posición del array con `$listaReuniones[0]`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Comparto solución para que se vea como lo he dejado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien ha dicho @David_helo, he quitado el bucle y accedo a la primera posición de mi array y luego a cada uno de sus propiedades:

```
echo   "<table class='tabla_reuniones'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Asunto</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th>Comienzo</th>
                            <th>Finalización</th>
                            <th>Coste</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

            <tr>
            <td>".$listaReuniones[0]->getAsuntoModelo()."</td>
            <td>".$listaReuniones[0]->getFechaModelo()."</td>
            <td>".$listaReuniones[0]->getInicioModelo()."</td>
            <td>".$listaReuniones[0]->getFinModelo()."</td>
            <td>".$listaReuniones[0]->getCosteEstimadoModelo()."</td>
            </tr>
                </tbody>
                    </table>";
```